# PHP and Javascript location.hash with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a CSS modal that pops up when a user clicks a button on my page.  I use some of the information from the post back to generate the modal.  At the end of my code that generates the modal, I use:

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.hash = "#confirm";</script>';`

to make the modal appear.

This works perfectly for me in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and IE10.  However, in IE9, when I click the button, the URL does get appended with the #confirm tag, but the modal doesn't appear and the page appears to lose all of my CSS styling.  I can't figure out if I'm coming across an IE9 bug, if I'm doing something wrong, or if it just isn't compatible with my approach to this modal.

Appreciate any advice or insight!

UPDATE TO SOME QUESTIONS:
I render the modal using a function that generates the code:

```
//CONFIRM MODAL
function FUNCTION_confirm_modal($modal_header, $modal_content, $modal_button1, $modal_link1, $modal_button2, $modal_link2)
{
    //BUILD SUBMIT SUCCESS MODAL        
    $confirm_modal = '
    <div id="confirm" class="modal">
    <div>
    <h4 class="warn">'.$modal_header.'</h4>
    '.$modal_content.'
    <fieldset id="modalSubmitAreaRight">
    <a href="'.$modal_link1.'" class="shortButton">'.$modal_button1.'</a><a href="'.$modal_link2.'" class="longButton">'.$modal_button2.'</a>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div>';    

    //RETURN DATA
    return $confirm_modal;
}
```

Then, on my content page, I do this:

```
print_r($confirm_modal);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.hash = "#confirm";</script>';
```

The actual appearance / visibility / etc of the modal is controlled by my CSS.  If you need to see that as well, just let me know.  And thank you!

HERE IS THE CSS THAT OPENS/CLOSED THE MODAL:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
overflow: scroll;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 1000;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
visibility:hidden;
pointer-events: none;
}

/* SHOW MODAL */

.modal:target {
visibility: visible;
pointer-events: auto;
}

/* MODAL CONTENT */

.modal > div {
width: 500px;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
-webkit-animation: minimise 500ms linear;
-moz-animation: minimise 500ms linear;
-o-animation: minimise 500ms linear;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

/* MODAL CALL ANIMATION */

.modal:target > div {
-webkit-animation-name: bounce;
-moz-animation-name: bounce;
-o-animation-name: bounce;
}

/* MODAL ANIMATION */

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  55% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  75% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes minimise {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  100% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  55% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  75% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  100% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes minimise {
  0% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  100% {
-moz-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
-o-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you checking the hash to display the modal? Problem is most likely not with the link that sets the hash, especially if it works (puts the hash in the url).

Comment: How is your modal window opened?  The error is with that code, not with this line.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks for the feedback!  Just posted additional code.  Let me know if that's what you were after?

Comment: That code just puts a `<div>` on the page (and scrolls to it).  How do you *open* the modal window?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry - just posted the CSS code that opens/closes the modal.

Comment: @Jason: There's a lot of CSS and HTML stuff that IE9 doesn't support.  Wonder if that's what's happening here :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I had a feeling that might be the case.  Darn!

Comment: @Jason: Are you sure IE9 is running in IE9 mode (do you have the right `DOCTYPE`)?  Because I took your code, put into an jsFiddle, and it works for me in IE 9.  http://jsfiddle.net/ELD2G/

Comment: @RocketHazmat Strange...yes, definitely running in IE9 mode.  My DOCTYPE is set for HTML5....  `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Weird - just tried your jsFiddle in IE9 and it appeared to work for me there as well.  Don't understand why it's failing on my page then....strange one!

Comment: @Jason: Yeah, I'm not sure what's wrong.  Sorry :(

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hi there - was doing some testing and noticed what's happening.  I put IE9 in developer mode, and when the page loads it's in IE9 mode.  However, when I click the button and the post/modal code runs, it puts itself into Quirks mode.  Ever encountered that before?  Thank you!

Comment: @Jason: Are you sure you have a `DOCTYPE` on the page?  You can also try to add this to your `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm positive - it shows up correctly when the page first renders.  I've been debugging in the console and I think it's my actual submit button that's breaking it.  The console is giving me a Syntax error for the onclick event for my button:  `onclick="document.modify-request.closeButton.disabled=true; document.modify-request.closeButton.value='Saving...'; document.modify-request.submit();"`  Not sure why though - it seems valid to me?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Nevermind, I took out the onclick code and it still failed.  When the postback occurs, the console reads HTML1113 Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks.  The hunt continues!

Comment: @RocketHazmat - OK!  Figured it out.  When I echo the modal code, that's appearing at the very top of the page source above the doctype declaration, etc.  I just tried to echo the meta tag (X-UA IE edge, etc.) before that code and that did the trick!

Comment: @Jason: That would do it!  Your document needs to be in the right order :-)